# Reading values from a file

Tags: python, file

My task is to read 10 numbers from a ,txt file and then print their sum:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
sumofn=0
for i in range(1, 10):
    x = f.readline(i)
    x = int(x)
    sumofn += x

print(sumofn)
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the simple solution. If your values are comma separated, you can use the split() method:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
sumofn = 0
for i in range(1, 10):
    for x in f.readlines():
            x = int(x)
            sumofn += x

print(sumofn)
```

Here is also the split() method. It is used if your values are comma separated and space separated:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
sumofn = 0
for i in range(1, 10):
    for x in f.readlines():
        y = x.split(',')
        for x in y:
            x = int(x)
            sumofn += x

print(sumofn)
```

Comment: Does the first part really work? What about the indentation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your file has int values only because you used conversion `int()`. In this case, you can use regex pattern `r'\d+'` simply (instead of the `r'\d+(\.\d+)?'`) but the following code covers the case that the file contains float values.

```
import re
result = 0
with open('data.txt', 'r') with f:
    line = f.readline()
    match = re.search(r'\d+(\.\d+)?', line)
    if match:
        result += float(match.group())
print(result)
```

Please give it a shot.

Comment: my txt file is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 and all numbers are after enter key, re.search in your solution doesnt work

Comment: Do you mean that your file can have many integer numbers in a single line?

Comment: Even though every number starts with line break, the regular expression should be able to extract the numbers.

Comment: Every line starts with number and then new line starts

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is your best friend

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
     print(sum([int(i) for i in f.read().split('\n') if i != '']))
```

btw '\n' means it's a linebreak; the enter you press while writing text file. Because it has '\n' when you read the file.